# Prompt_toolkit custom event, like input from non user function

Tags: python, event-handling, hook, handler, prompt-toolkit

I'm trying to find some documentation about how to add a custom handler, hook etc. to automatically add text, or generally modify the full screen app.

I'd want to render a dict received via a named pipe (from another terminal app running in another window) and display the dict in a treeview control (if anyone has recommendations for a treeview lib that'd be great!).

So the event would listen to the pipe and update a prompt control when received.

The references I found were below, but they aren't too descriptive:

[readthedocs](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/advanced_topics/input_hooks.html)

[example of input hook](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/971b56690c9288ecb6fb2aecd2bd82f7f892fac5/examples/prompts/inputhook.py)

TIA!